# Is there a consistent way to deal with libraries being extrenalized in Scala 2.11?

Tags: swing, scala, parsing

I have painfully come across the facts that `scala.util.parsing` and `scala.swing` are apparently no more bundled in Scala 2.11. Each time, I had to google for the right line to add to an sbt configuration, or to find the right link for where to download the jar file.

In case there are other libraries that moved out, how am I supposed to know these things? Or am I supposed to rely only on questions from people having the same problem on Stackoverflow? The Scala Swing project [on github](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing) does not even document these info.

I like creating Eclipse projects on the fly, and making them depend on other projects in the same workspace, without going through sbt, and it is annoying to run into these library disappearance cases on every computer/workspace where I do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modularization (what you call *externalizing*) has been discussed for a good while on the [scala-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-user). But the *canonical* place where to find this information is in the release notes. While you may not want to read all of those, I would strongly advise reading at least the release notes for a *major version* of any language you use. Case in point, the [release notes for Scala 2.11.0](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.11.0):

> Modularization 
>   The core Scala standard library jar has shed 20% of its
>   bytecode. The modules for xml, parsing, swing as well as the
>   (unsupported) continuations plugin and library are available
>   individually or via scala-library-all. Note that this artifact has
>   weaker binary compatibility guarantees than scala-library – as
>   explained above. The compiler has been modularized internally, to
>   separate the presentation compiler, scaladoc and the REPL. We hope
>   this will make it easier to contribute. In this release, all of these
>   modules are still packaged in scala-compiler.jar. We plan to ship them
>   in separate JARs in 2.12.x.

Comment: Removing Swing and XML specifically has been on the roadmap for at least 2 years, I think.

Comment: I try to follow the project, but didn't know about scala-library-all. That should be a "getting started" item. Maybe activator simplifies it? Scala-IDE ought to make it trivial to depend on it, and probably on anything in the community projects list. https://github.com/scala/make-release-notes/blob/2.11.x/projects-2.11.md